# How to assign each group's first value to "1" and rest "0" in R Dataframe

Tags: r

Business Context:

A retail chain with multiple stores across the country launches  coupon campaign at different points of time across the all the stores to its customers and I working on which coupon performs
better and calculating response rate for each of the coupons.

I have arrived at a dataframe like below,

```
"customerID Couponid CouponExpiryDate RetailstoreID   Visitdate campaignresponse
AA1          111        01-10-18       B3B12           01-01-18         1     
AA1          111        01-10-18       B3B12           01-02-18         1
AA2          111        01-10-18       B3B51           01-25-18         0
AA3          121        01-25-18       B54D3           01-14-18         1
AA1          111        01-10-18       B3B12           01-11-18         0   
AA4          115        01-15-18       B3B12           01-01-18         1     
AA3          111        01-25-18       B54D3           01-23-18         1
......
```

Issue:

I used a simple mutate statement to calculate the last column "Campaignresponse"

Assume OrderDate = "12-31-17"

```
df<-df%>%mutate(campaignresponse = Visitdate >=OrderDate & (Visitdate <=CouponExpiryDate ))%>%replace_na(list((campaignresponse =0))
```

If you look at the above data frame especially row no:2 and row no:7, it shows "1" but i want that to be "0". Because in my case, a customer can respond to coupon campaign only once 
and if the visit date is before the expiry date it should be 1. But there are some customers who has visitied the store twice or more within the campaign period and my code calculates
them to be responded to the campaign and it assigns a value "1" but that is wrong.

Ideally I want something like below,

```
customerID Couponid CouponExpiryDate RetailstoreID   Visitdate campaignresponse
AA1          111        01-10-18       B3B12           01-01-18         1     
AA1          111        01-10-18       B3B12           01-02-18         0
AA2          111        01-10-18       B3B51           01-25-18         0
AA3          121        01-25-18       B54D3           01-14-18         1
AA1          111        01-10-18       B3B12           01-11-18         0   
AA4          115        01-15-18       B3B12           01-01-18         1     
AA3          121        01-25-18       B54D3           01-23-18         0
......
```

Can someone please help me with this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df<-df %>% group_by(customerID, Couponid) %>% 
 dplyr::mutate(campaignresponse = as.integer(Visitdate >=OrderDate & (Visitdate <=CouponExpiryDate ) & row_number()==1))
```

You want to add a condition that the row is the first of all rows with the same customer id and coupon id (this assumes the data is already sorted by date - if not, add an arrange() line).

Result:

```
# A tibble: 7 x 6
# Groups:   customerID, Couponid [5]
  customerID Couponid CouponExpiryDate RetailstoreID Visitdate  campaignresponse
  <fct>         <int> <date>           <fct>         <date>                <int>
1 AA1             111 2018-01-10       B3B12         2018-01-01                1
2 AA1             111 2018-01-10       B3B12         2018-01-02                0
3 AA2             111 2018-01-10       B3B51         2018-01-25                0
4 AA3             121 2018-01-25       B54D3         2018-01-14                1
5 AA1             111 2018-01-10       B3B12         2018-01-11                0
6 AA4             115 2018-01-15       B3B12         2018-01-01                1
7 AA3             111 2018-01-25       B54D3         2018-01-23                1
```

Comment: Thanks!!. I tried your approach. First i sorted the visit date and used your code. But it throws up this error "argument "x" is missing, with no default"

Comment: This usually means that it's using the `plyr`'s package `mutate` rather than `dplyr` - either because `dplyr` isn't loaded, or because you loaded `plyr` after loading `dplyr` (which you shouldn't, really). Either way, I updated the code, and it should work fine now.

Comment: I used plyr package to use "rbind.fill", which was throwing some error in dplyr package. But yea your new code worked. great!!!